# Cannot use CoreML model to make prediction

Tags: swift, coreml

I have succesfully compiled and saved an MLmodel and I am able to use it in swift code. However, when I try to use the same model by loading and compiling it I get this error. If I print the model I get all relevant info. However, I cannot make predictions. The "let myprediction = try loadedmodel.predictions(from : totestTable)" line that throws the error can actually work if I place it in the part of code that follows the training of the model.

It has to be some type of declaration/initialization.

```
func machinlearningTest( id : String){

    do {
        let compiledModelUrl: URL = try MLModel.compileModel(at: URL(string : "/Users/panos/Downloads/" + id + ".mlmodel")!)
        let loadedmodel  = try MLModel.init(contentsOf: compiledModelUrl)
        let testTable = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/panos/Downloads/test.csv"))
        let testclassifierColumns = ["parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter3", "parameter4"]
        let totestTable = testTable[testclassifierColumns]
        let myprediction = try loadedmodel.predictions(from : totestTable)
        print(loadedmodel)

        }
    catch {}
 }
```

Comment: I've never tried it but I don't think you can use MLDataTable to make predictions.

Comment: this exact line actually works if I place it in the same instance of code that produces the model. It simply does not work if I save it and reload it. Is there a way to extract the MLclassifier from the loaded MLmodel?

Comment: It works when you create the model because that uses the Create ML framework. But when making predictions with that model, it uses Core ML, which is a different framework. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me look at the right direction.

To answer my own question, the model has to be loaded beforehand someway in order for the class to be initialised. Or, the model relevant swift code (class declarations etc) to be included.